# ListView issue in Android eclipse

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am very new in android development. i am adding details to my sqllite table(id,name,number). Now i try to list that. I just want to list name only . and when click on particular name shows number of particular name. Now i am try to list the names. my code is.

details.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    >
<ListView
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

DetailOperation.java

```
    public class DetailOperations {
private DataBase dbHelper;
private String[] DETAILS_TABLE_COLUMNS = { DataBase.DETAIL_ID, DataBase.DETAIL_NAME,DataBase.DETAIL_NO };
private SQLiteDatabase database;
public DetailOperations(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new DataBase(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public List getAllDetails(){
    List Details=new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBase.DETAILS,
            DETAILS_TABLE_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        Detail de=parseDetail(cursor);
        Details.add(de);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return Details;

}
private Detail parseDetail(Cursor cursor) {
    Detail d = new Detail();
    d.setId((cursor.getInt(0)));
    d.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    d.setnumber(cursor.getString(2));
    return d;
     }
        }
```

Details.java

```
   public class Details extends ListActivity {
private DetailOperations detailDBoperation;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);
    detailDBoperation=new DetailOperations(this);
    detailDBoperation.open();
    List<Detail> values=detailDBoperation.getAllDetails();
    List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
    {
      names.add(values.get(i).getName()); 
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
   // List values=detailDBoperation.getAllDetails();
   // ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list ofDetail ->Name);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    detailDBoperation.open();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    detailDBoperation.close();
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Detail.java

```
  public class Detail {
private int id;
private String name;
private String number;

public long getId() {   return id;}
public void setId(int id) { this.id = id;   }
public String getName() {   return this.name;   }
public void setName(String name) {  this.name = name;   }
public String getNumber(){  return this.number; }
public void setnumber(String number){   this.number=number; }
   }
```

but i got the output list like that

```
  com.example.experiments.Detail@417c38d0
  com.example.experiments.Detail@417c3a10
  com.example.experiments.Detail@417c3ab0
```

Comment: u mean when u click particular name u r getting com.example...?

Comment: @Monica:no when details.xml opens i got this list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Code Like Following

```
 List values=detailDBoperation.getAllDetails();
 List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
 {
   names.add(values.get(i).getName()); 
 }
 ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
```

Comment: replace all your List Declarations with List<Detail> details=new ArrayList<Detail>();

Comment: u didn't specify object type in all your List Declarations Please do that

Comment: it show error in logcat when running  09-25 01:15:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.experiments/com.example.experiments.Details}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.experiments.Detail

Comment: change List<Detail> in getAllDetails() Method and also in  its return type

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your array to string by adding

```
  Details.add(de.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here
   getAllDetails() return List Details which is list of Detail de type Object.You need to pass List of Detail ->Name List in  ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list of Detail ->Name);

Comment: this is not complete statement i want to say that you shold pass List of String like List<String> DetailNAme=new ArrayList<String>();